# connecting android to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I have been trying this tutorial. It doent show any errors but on emulator only the url that i gave is appearing!

my connection string was:

```
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";
```

(i used 10.0.2.2 as i am working on local host)

when i checked my logcat it showed me dis:

```
error parsing data org.json.JsonException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I really dont know whats wrong with my code. Can anyone please help me. I really need help on this for my final year project.

This is my android java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView txt1, txt2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout
        // resources
        // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ip);

        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        txt1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rootLayout.addView(txt1);
        setContentView(rootLayout);

        // Set the text and call the connect function.
        txt1.setText("Connecting...");
        // call the method to run the data retreival
        txt1.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));

    }

    public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

        InputStream is = null;

        String result = "";
        // the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "1970"));


        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // parse json data

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag",
                        "longitude: " + json_data.getDouble("longitude")
                                + ", latitude: "
                                + json_data.getDouble("latitude"));
                // Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return returnString;
    }

}
```

This is my php code

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","sugi");
mysql_select_db("android");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

This is mysql query

```
CREATE TABLE people (

  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,

  name VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,

  sex BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',

  birthyear INT NOT NULL

  )
```

This is what its display when i type "http://10.0.2.2/index.php" on IE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try and print the output you get from your server. it seems its not clear JSON that gets returned. This part

```
Value <br of type
```

Looks like there is a hard enter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Fix you php warning and the result of the index.php should be a valid JSON response.

The variable `$_REQUEST['year']` is not defined, probably because you didn't send it with your request. Your variable `nameValuePairs` is never added to your request...

Comment: Hi, thank alot for the help. I am new to php and mysql. Can you tell me what do i need to do to send my request?

Answer (score 0):

The server is likely returning an error that begins with

```
<BR />
```

You can verify this by adding a line to this block of code:

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

            /////////////////////////////////
            // ADD THIS
            Log.i("log_tag","Line reads: " + line);

        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

Then run the program and check your log. It will show you what information is received from the server.

For instance, if your PHP configuration does not include the JSON library, you will get an error. You may be using an older version of PHP. If you are using a managed server like 1and1 or GoDaddy, you may just need to edit your .htaccess file so that your site uses PHP5.